# how to solve Virtual host my_vhost experienced an error on node in rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

The disk is full,when I deleted log file and restart my rabbitmq(3.7.15),throw this error:

```
Virtual host my_vhost experienced an error on node rabbit@myRabbit and may be inaccessible
```

only my_vhost has this problem,other virtual host is fine.how to solve this problem?